# Disable zoomOnclick when initializing Google maps with "Gmaps4rails"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, gmaps4rails

This is my javascript :

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {scrollwheel: false, navigationControl: false, mapTypeControl: false, scaleControl: false,
    draggable: false, streetViewControl: false, scrollwheel: false, zoomControl: false, disableDoubleClickZoom: true, overviewMapControl: false}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
      markers = handler.addMarkers(#{raw @hash.to_json});
      handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();
    });
```

Where in this code should I put isZoomOnclick(), or zoomOnclick() options? All search restults that I've done doesn't give me this, if someone finds out please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way:

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { clusterer: cluterer_options } });
```

Comment: Why? Could you explain what is the problem in his post?

Comment: @AntoJurković there is no pb in the post... I'm just answering... zoomOnclick is a clusterer option right?